# delete items from database

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello i'm trying to delete 3 items from database in a ListView

This is in my editpage java

```
bouton_supprimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 mDatabaseHelper.Delete(selectedID);//suprime les données de la data
 Intent intent = new Intent(EditUser.this, PageUser.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 toastMessage("L'utilsateur a été supprimer");
 }
});
```

And this is in my databasehelper java

```
public void Delete(int id){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

I want that when I click on the delete button, it deletes the selected items and returns me to the previous page where the userlist is.

Comment: what issue you are facing here?

Comment: when I click on the delete button, it return me to the previous page and tells me that the user has been deleted but it still in the list.

Comment: have you notify your adapter?

Comment: no, but I have to do something in it to delete ?

Comment: check the value of "query"

Comment: thank you i just saw that the value of "id" is  "-1"

Comment: but still dosen't work and I don't know if I have to change the value of "id"